# Whats the best way to upload images using cakephp 1.3

Tags: php, cakephp

Firstly I'm totally new to cakephp and only a novice with php. I want to be able to upload image files which correspond with records in a table charities which I have. It would be good if the images were processed a little, ie maybe a few different sizes of thumbnail would be created when they got uploaded, maybe even there would be a way of cropping the images in case they're too large for what I want.

I've had a good look around for the past bunch of hours and found loads of tutorials and behaviours and helpers etc which purport to do what I want, but none which I've tried seems to work for me. I believe issues to do with them being written for old versions of cake.

Can anyone suggest what is the best way to achieve what I want? Is there maybe something in built in cakephp 1.3 which removes the need for plug-ins or behaviours?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to do? upload images or process them? Cakephp doesn't have a built-in image processor, but does have the Html helper to help upload files. Its up to you to process and save the files. have a look at the GD library or imagemagick to do image processing.

Answer (score 0):

Simple file uploading in CakePHP is so easy. Cropping or editing images is another case. There is no simple way to do this in Cake. The good news is, there are a lot of plug-ins out there you could use. Most of them are in JavaScript(jQuery, Prototype). Here is a good [example](http://www.gastonrobledo.com.ar/cropzoom/index.html).

I suggest you should read more about using javascript files in CakePHP.

Answer (score 0):

The behaviour I use for uploading images is [Meio Upload](https://github.com/jrbasso/MeioUpload), you can attach it to any model and set certain image dimensions to save the image as.

All the setup instructions you need are in the behaviours read me.